# Fourier Stability Analysis

Tags: complex-numbers, numerical-methods, fourier-analysis

Consider this problem

> Apply the Fourier stability test to the difference equation
> $$
> u_m^{n+1}=\frac{1}{2}\left(2-5 \mu+6 \mu^2\right) u_m^n+\frac{2}{3} \mu(2-3 \mu)\left(u_{m-1}^n+u_{m+1}^n\right)-\frac{1}{12} \mu(1-6 \mu)\left(u_{m-2}^n+u_{m+2}^n\right),
> $$
> where $m \in \mathbb{Z}$. Deduce that the test is satisfied if and only if $0 \leq \mu \leq \frac{2}{3}$.

This looked relatively innocent until I calculated
$$
H(\theta) = \frac{1}{6}(6-16\mu + 24 \mu^2)-\frac{1}{3}\mu (1-6 \mu)\left(\sin \theta -\frac{2(2-3\mu}{1-6\mu}\right)^2+ \frac{4}{3} \mu \frac{(2-3 \mu)^2}{1-6\mu}.
$$
The method requires us to show that $| H| \leq 1$ if and only if $\mu$ is in the above range. This seems like it’s going be very hard as the issue is that depending on the value of $\mu$ I have to take $\sin $ accordingly to maximise. Moreover, I lack the absolute value which will surely provide difficulties.

**Question:** How do I proceed?

**Reference:** Here is a reference for the method

[image]

Comment: Hi. The difference equation is $\sum_{k=r}^{s} b_{k} u_{m+k}^{n+1}=\sum_{k=r}^{s} c_{k} u_{m+k}^{n}$. Also, I made a type on the LaTeX. It should be correct now.